# Filter All Data Using Start and End Date Column

Tags: mysql, sql

How should I filter all data from start to end date? I have 2 columns - one for the start date and another for the end column.

I want to select all the data having a specific start and end date.

For example:
August 2018 to September 2018

**Data:**

[image]

Here's my query:

```
SELECT * FROM project_monitoring pm INNER JOIN status s ON pm.status_ID = s.status_ID WHERE /*select all started from this date format MDY or MY or Y */ pm.proj_DateStarted = '2018-04-19' /*this end date format MDY or MY or Y */ pm.proj_DateEnded = '2018-03-08'
```

Comment: Even with a name like spacetime, I find it peverse that a project might end before it even begins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correct.

You can try to use `BETWEEN`

```
SELECT * FROM project_monitoring pm 
INNER JOIN status s ON pm.status_ID = s.status_ID 
WHERE (pm.proj_DateStarted BETWEEN '2018-08-01' AND '2018-09-01') 
OR (pm.proj_DateEnded BETWEEN '2018-08-01' AND '2018-09-01')
```

Comment: Let me try this ;)

Comment: It should be..
(Start between start and end) or (End between end and start) edit ur date on ur answer :) thanks

Comment: @スペースタイム Probably not the best idea to tell the respondents what they should be doing.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select * from project_monitoring pm 
INNER JOIN status s ON pm.status_ID = s.status_ID 
where pm.proj_datestarted>=yourstartdate and 
pm.proj_dateended<=yourenddate
```

Comment: Please describe what you are getting now and what your expected results are

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM Table_name WHERE (start_date BETWEEN  aaa AND bbb ) AND (last_date BETWEEN ccc AND ddd) .

I think this should work pretty straightforward if I am understanding the question right.